# Kafka Streams TimestampExtractor

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hi everybody I have a question about TimestampExtractor and Kafka Streams....

In our application there is a possibility of receiving out-of-order events, so I like to order the events depending on a business date inside of the payload instead in point of time they placed in the topic.

For this purpose I programmed a custom TimestampExtractor to be able to pull the timestamp from the payload. Everything until I told here worked perfectly but when I build the KTable to this topic, I discerned that the event that I receive out-of-order (from Business point of view it is not last event but it received at the end) displayed as last state of the object while ConsumerRecord having the timestamp from the payload.

I don't know may be it was my mistake to assume Kafka Stream will fix this out-of-order problem with TimestampExtractor.

Then during debugging I saw that if the TimestampExtractor returns -1 as result Kafka Streams are ignoring the message and TimestampExtractor also delivering the timestamp of the last accepted Event, so I build a logic that realise the following check (payloadTimestamp < previousTimestamp) return -1, which achieves the logic I want but I am not sure I am sailing on dangerous waters or not.

Am I allowed to deal with a logic like this or what other ways exist to deal with out-of-order events in Kafka streams....

Thx for answers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Kafka 2.0), `KTable`s don't consider timestamps when they are updated, because the assumption is, that there is no out-of-order data in the input topic. The reason for this assumption is the "single writer principle" -- it's assumed, that for compacted KTable input topic, there is only one producer per key, and thus, there won't be any out-of-order data with regard to single keys.

It's a know issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6521

For your fix: it's not 100% correct or safe to do this "hack":

- First, assume you have two different messages with two different key `<key1, value1, 5>, <key2, value2, 3>`. The second record with timestamp 3 is later, compared to the first record with timestamp 5. However, both have different keys and thus, you actually want to put the second record into the KTable. Only if you have two record with the same key, you want to drop late arriving data IHMO.
- Second, if you have two records with the same key and the second one if out-of-order and you crash before processing the second one, the `TimestampExtractor` looses the timestamp of the first record. Thus on restart, it would not discard the out-of-order record.

To get this right, you will need to filter "manually" in your application logic instead of the stateless and key-agnostic `TimestampExtractor`. Instead of reading the data via `builder#table()` you can read it as a stream, and apply an `.groupByKey().reduce()` to build the `KTable`. In you `Reducer` logic, you compare the timestamp of the new and old record and return the record with the larger timestamp.